# Preventing premature monomorphization of constrained polymorphic values

Tags: haskell, constraint-kinds

This is a question concerning constrained polymorphic values, i.e.: values of type `forall f. cxt f => a`, where `cxt` is some constraint.

As normal, for such a value to be used, we need some reified constraints type:

```
data Dict (c :: k -> Constraint) (a :: k) where
  Dict :: c a => Dict c a
```

Now, using such a value directly is simple enough:

```
runPolymorphicValue :: forall c y b. Dict c y -> (forall a. c a => b) -> b
runPolymorphicValue Dict x = x @y
```

However, I'm having trouble actually calling this function.

```
runPolymorphicValueWrapper :: forall c y b. Dict c y -> (forall a. c a => b) -> b
runPolymorphicValueWrapper d x = runPolymorphicValue d x
```

gives this error message:

```
error:
• Could not deduce: c a0 arising from a use of ‘x’
  from the context: c a
    bound by a type expected by the context:
               forall (a :: k1). c a => b
```

Even though `x` has the desired type `forall a. c a => b`, it appears that GHC has attempted to monomorphize `x` immediately upon use, instantiating the `c a` constraint into `c a0` for unknown `a0`. Obviously, this fails.

In contrast, this definition works fine:

```
runPolymorphicValue' :: forall c y b. Dict c y -> (forall a. Dict c a -> b) -> b
runPolymorphicValue' Dict f = (f (Dict @c @y))

runPolymorphicValueWrapper' :: forall c y b. Dict c y -> (forall a. Dict c a -> b) -> b
runPolymorphicValueWrapper' d x = runPolymorphicValue' d x
```

So, how can I actually call a function which takes a parameter of type `forall f. cxt f => a`?

---

Broader context:

My end goal is to write a function `mapAll` which lifts a mapping from types (or some other kind) to values `* -> a` into a mapping from lists of types to lists of values `[*] -> [a]`, i.e.:   `mapAll :: (All cxt fs) => (forall f. cxt f => a) -> [a]`. Here, `All cxt fs` means that `fs` is some list of types,  and `cxt f` holds for each `f`  in `fs` (see [docs](http://www.cubix-framework.com/doc/cubix-compdata-1.0.1/Data-Comp-Multi.html)). I am able to write this function if I use a `forall f. Dict cxt f -> a` instead of a `forall f. cxt f => a`.

---

**Edit**

It looks like using `forall a. c a => Proxy a -> b` instead also works. This should do the job for now, but I'll leave up this question. It sounds like the issue is, indeed, premature monomorphization.

For comparison, I had earlier tried using `forall a. c a => () -> b`, which gave the same error as the original example.

Comment: Last I checked, `TypeApplications` didn't really work for higher-order functions. Can you pass a function that takes a `Proxy` or a `Proxy#`, or whose type is `Tagged`?

Comment: I'm surprised there's a difference, but: yes I can.

Comment: The rules are that all occurrences of polymorphic values are *always* and *immediately* applied to type parameters, whether implicit or explicit, and that holes of polymorphic type are also *always* and *immediately* filled in with "type lambdas". In your case, `runPolymorphicValue d x` means `runPolymorphicValue d (\@a -> x @_)` and, oops, that `_` type cannot be deduced. It's a pain, yes.